# Webservice with Python client

Tags: python, webservice-client

I have a application wrote in Python. Now I must run many instances of this application, but it is one problem. Many instances have one device and access to this device must be synchronised.

I think that the best way to synchronise these instances is to build webservice.

In which language you suggest to write webservice. Python/Django or .NET? How my client can edit data in webservice? I have only found tutorials with read data - not write.

Thanks for responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In which language you suggest to write webservice.

Python/Django

> How my client can edit data in webservice?

Read about [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer).  A POST request instead of a GET request is an update.

Use [Piston](http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home) with Django.